# nginx how to redirect app.sub.domain to app.domain

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

Can you please suggest how to configure nginx to redirect:

***.sub.domain.com -> *.domain.com**

app1.sub.domain.com -> app1.domain.com

app2.sub.domain.com -> app2.domain.com

...

This is what I was trying to do:

```
{
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^(\w+)\.sub\.domain\.com$;
    return 301 $scheme://$app.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

and after redirect of app1.sub.domain.com got:

```
Location: http://.domain.com/
```

Comment: Please show some effort. Goto the official documentation at nxinx.org, read about the redirect parameter and if you still need assistance update your question with the configuration you tried.

Comment: updated question seems to be a duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/583944/nginx-redirect-all-old-domain-subdomains-to-new-one

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me on AWS Linux with nginx 1.6.2
But it works fine on Ubuntu with nginx 1.4.6